# Call same function on page load and when form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $("#GetLog").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                 //some code

         });
   });
   <form id="GetLog"> 
         <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

I want to call this function when the page loads and when the user presses the submit button.

I have tried `document.getElementById("GetLog").submit()` on page load but it does call the function.

Comment: You should really make this question easier to read.

Comment: I thought it was fine. What's your specific gripe? It's not literature but it's readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining a separate function and call on load and on submit

```
function ajaxCall(){
   $.ajax({
             //some code

     });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ajaxCall();
});

$("#GetLog").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ajaxCall();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a non-anonymous function, and just pass that function in to the various listeners.

Example:

```
function submitFtn = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
             //some code

     } 
$("#GetLog").submit(submitFtn);
$(document).ready(submitFtn)

<form id="GetLog"> 
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function(){
    //call the function
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#GetLog',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            //some code

        });
    });
})
<form id="GetLog"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#GetLog").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
             //some code

      });
   });
   //I want to call this function when page loads
   $('#GetLog').trigger('submit');

});
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to submit form on page load :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $("#GetLog").submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            ...
       })
 }).submit();
});
```